# Chrome bloqueia leitura de arquivo

Tags: php, google-chrome

Boa noite, pessoal do Stack Overflow, eu estou escrevendo um sistema de playlist em PHP, ainda está em desenvolvimento então para testar a execução das músicas eu listei os links de cada música do diretório escolhido, mas aí os links não me levavam ao arquivo como em *file:///home/(...)musica.mp3*, mas copiando o link e colando em uma nova guia o Chrome reproduziu a música. Depois de muitas tentativas e mudanças no código-fonte, eu tentei debugar no próprio Chrome e recebi como resultado 
*Not allowed to load local resource: 
file:///home/zenas/Musica/[1967]%20-%20Magical%20Mystery%20Tour/04%20-%20Blue%20Jay%20Way.mp3*. 
Como resolver esse problema?! Aqui estão os códigos:

Index.php

```
 <?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
echo '<form action="list.php">';
echo "<h4>Write your songs folder</h4><br>";
echo "<h5>(DON'T WRITE A BAR IN THE END OR WRITE ANY SPECIAL CHARACTER)</h5>";
echo '<input type="text" name="folder">';
echo '<input type="submit">';
echo "</form>";
```

list.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

$folder = $_GET["folder"];
$files  = "{$folder}/".$_GET['/*.*'];

if(isset($_GET['folder']) && file_exists("{$folder}/".$_GET['/*.*'])){

$fold = opendir($folder);

    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($fold))) { 

        if (substr($filename,-4) == ".mp3") { 
        echo "<a href=\"file://$folder/$filename\">$filename</a><br>"; 
}

}

}
```

Comment: Não pode abrir arquivos pelo protocolo `file://`. Restrição básica de segurança.

Comment: Eu não entendo, mas então por quê ao usar file:// numa nova guia eu posso acessar o arquivo? De qualquer forma, quando eu retiro o file:// do código, o PHP interpreta que o link leva a uma pasta dentro de localhost, o que não é  o caso. Mas obrigado pela tentativa =D

Comment: Pelo HTML, abrir um arquivo local não é permitido. Já quando vc coloca direto na barra de URL, o navegador te leva diretamente ao filesystem. Não há bloqueio nesse caso pois é vc quem coloca o endereço explicitamente. Se quiser abrir esse arquivo normalmente pelo HTML, coloque-o no protocolo http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é o Chrome.
Seu servidor Web não tem permissão para fazer leituras de arquivos locais por questões de segurança (Not allowed to load local resource = Não é permitido carregar recurso [arquivo] local).
Uma forma de contornar o problema é simplesmente mover sua pasta de músicas para dentro da pasta onde seu PHP está rodando. Se essa pasta é /var/ww, então:
`mv /home/zenas/Musica /var/www/Musica`

Ou, então, você pode fazer um link simbólico de sua pasta de Músicas para a pasta do Web Server:
`ln -s /home/zenas/Musica /var/www/Musica`
Nesse último caso, é importante configurar seu servidor web para permitir links simbólicos, ou terás o erro "403 PROIBIDO" ao tentar acessá-los.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!